# Finding $\lim_{x\to{0}^+}\frac{\exp[-(\log(x))^2]}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find 
$$\lim_{x\to{0}^+}\frac{\exp[-(\log(x))^2]}{x}$$ 
by using l'Hospital rule.

However, after taking the derivative of the top and bottom. I just end up with:
$$\frac{-2\exp[-(\log(x))^2]\log(x)}{x}$$ 
for the top. Which is essentially the same problem as what I started with.

Comment: Usually the first mistake is attempting to use L'Hopital's rule. Instead learn how to use asymptotic expansions. See my profile for some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (without l'Hospital rule). Note that
$$\frac{\exp[-(\log(x))^2]}{x}=\exp(-(\log(x))^2-\log(x))=
\exp(-(\log(x))^2(1+o(1))).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: $$-(\log(x))^2-\log(x)=- \left( \log(x) \right) \left( \log(x)-1 \right)$$

Comment: I got it, thanks Robert.